# Flutter send streamed multipart request not finishing and causing segfault

Tags: flutter, dart, http, streaming, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a multipart request via `http.StreamedRequest`. I am aware of `http.MultipartRequest`, however, it does not fit my needs (the API I'm trying to send the request to encodes arrays by sending the same attribute multiple times, which is not possible using the fields parameter of `http.MultipartRequest` since it is a `Map<String, String>`, which does not allow the same key to be inserted multiple times).

The file (with form-data name `document`) I'm trying to send is provided in form of a `Uint8List` (a .pdf file), in addition to a filename (in the following "some_filename.pdf", a pdf title (in the following "some_document_title") and an array of numbers (which I'm trying to add to the multipart request) with the attribute `tags`.

For instance, I want the array `tags=[1, 2, 3]`, `title="some_document_title"` and file to be encoded as follows:

```
--dart-http-boundary-rVI-TO32QXZlS.VAGKWpuhbt99woLKVVvjToGoT-MVOU1YGSpnQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
Content-type: text/plain

some_document_title
--dart-http-boundary-rVI-TO32QXZlS.VAGKWpuhbt99woLKVVvjToGoT-MVOU1YGSpnQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tags"
Content-type: text/plain

1
--dart-http-boundary-rVI-TO32QXZlS.VAGKWpuhbt99woLKVVvjToGoT-MVOU1YGSpnQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tags"
Content-type: text/plain

2
--dart-http-boundary-rVI-TO32QXZlS.VAGKWpuhbt99woLKVVvjToGoT-MVOU1YGSpnQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tags"
Content-type: text/plain

3
--dart-http-boundary-rVI-TO32QXZlS.VAGKWpuhbt99woLKVVvjToGoT-MVOU1YGSpnQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="some_filename.pdf"
Content-type: application/octet-stream
```

After this part, I want to stream the file data.

The rough implementation looks like this:

```dart
Future<void> createDocument(Uint8List file, String filename, String title, List<int> tags) {
  
  final StreamedRequest request = StreamedRequest('POST', Uri.parse('some_url'));
 
  String boundary = "..."; // Generate random boundary string
  String contentType = "application/octet-stream";
  String body = "";
  Map<String, String> fields = {
    "title": title,
    // Some more fields left out for readability
  }; 

  for (final fieldKey in fields.keys) {
    body += _buildMultipartField(fieldKey, fields[fieldKey], boundary);
  }

  for (final tag in tags) {
    body += _buildMultipartField('tags', tag.toString(), boundary);
  }

  // Prepare file part
  body += "--$boundary" +
    '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="$filename"' +
    "\r\nContent-type: $contentType" +
    "\r\n\r\n";

  final closing = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";

  request.headers.addAll({
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary",
    "Content-Length": "${body.length + closing.length + file.lengthInBytes}"
  });
  
  // Add current body
  request.sink.add(utf8.encode(body));

  Stream.fromIterable(file).listen((chunk) => request.sink.add([chunk]))
    .onDone(() {
      // Add closing to multipart request
      request.sink.add(utf8.encode(closing));

      request.sink.close();
    });
  
  final StreamdResponse response = await IOClient().send(request);
  
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
   throw Error();
  }
}

  String _buildMultipartField(String fieldName, String value, String boundary) {
  return '--$boundary' +
      '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="$fieldName"' +
      '\r\nContent-type: text/plain' +
      '\r\n\r\n' +
      value +
      '\r\n';
}
```

Now, my current implementation produces the expected body, which is good, however, the streamed request does not seem to finish, and according to the DevTools Network page, the request is never sent.

Is the content-length relevant for the request to finish? I.e. is it possible that the request is not finishing because the server is still expecting data because the content-length is calculated incorrectly?

Also, I'm getting a segfault when hot restarting the application when the request is still pending (it never returns).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's `documentBytes` and where does it come from?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `file`, I corrected it.

Comment: However, I just solved it using the dart:io HttpClientRequest with basically the same procedure. But still, I don't understand why this does not finish.